# Basic question in finding the port of a website

Tags: ip

To my understanding, every time someone is hosting a service e.g. mysql server, there is always a server IP (or domain name) and a Port  needed to reach the service (e.g. [www.servername.com:3306](http://www.servername.com:3306)).

However, when I access sites such as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or [www.wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org), I 've no idea what port I am connecting to.

For instance, none of the following links [www.google.com:80](http://www.google.com:80), [www.google.com:8080](http://www.google.com:8080) work, and the case is the same for wikipedia. So the question is:

1. Is there a port already "embedded" in links such as google or wikipedia, or have I just not found the default port yet (i.e. it is not 80 or 8080)?
2. Is there a general way to break a link [www.somewebsite.com](http://www.somewebsite.com) into a host + port combination in the form of [www.somelink.com:[PORT]](http://www.somelink.com:%5BPORT%5D) ?

Comment: If a service uses its "well-known port" (as managed by IANA) then specifying the port explicitly is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you're accessing some site in your browser with `http://` in your URL, it means you're accessing `tcp/80` port. And in case of `https://` - `tcp/443`. You can override the port by adding `:<port_number>` after the host name, as you already mentioned in your question, example: `http://www.servername.com:8081`.

Comment: The IANA maintains a port number listing for every approved protocol. https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Comment: great, this is also the case for my example,so  www.google.com:443 and www.wikipedia.org:443 works as expected. I knew about 80 for http but ignored 443 for https, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's totally depends upon application developer decision to host application in server with any choosen specific ports .

By common application hosted ports are 443 with few of them will  still use customized ports for example TCP_8081 etc

Application team is responsible to create awareness among users to use domain name or URL with hosted ports to access application .